# ES6 & Ecmascript 2015

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Имеются сейчас две метки [es6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6) и [ecmascript-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015). Кажется, надо что-то с ними сделать.

На данный момент по метке [es6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6) есть 3 вопроса, по метке [ecmascript-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015) только 1 вопрос (мой, который задан раньше остальных трёх). [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) является официальным названием, которое должно бы заменить ES6, хотя, не похоже, чтобы так происходило в реальности.

В общем надо:

1. Выбрать основную метку, которую мы хотим использовать.
2. Объявить эти метки синонимами.

Обновление: на metaSO возник [такой же вопрос](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317710/4928642).

Comment: Я бы начал с того, что сделал описания для меток )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Описание уничтожается, если метка становится синонимом, имнип. Так что начинать стоит именно с определения основной метки.

Comment: @Discord: верно, уничтожается. Можно же его в обе метки поместить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Если репы недостаточно, то это потребует проверки обеих статей другими пользователями. Так как проверка нетривиальная (нужно проверить на копивио, как минимум), то это банально пустая трата времени. Ну и фарминг репы тоже.

Comment: @Discord: тогда описание нужно опубликовать прямо здесь.

Comment: @NickVolynkin В форме "можно" — согласен, "нужно" — нет. Описание метки и выбор основной метки среди синонимов ортогональны.

Comment: @Discord: описание позволяет понять, что метка вообще нужна, что обозначаемое явление существует. Для меня это пока что неочевидно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это версия языка по сути. Всё равно что "C# 6" или "C++14".

Comment: И почему не ответ Сквидварда принят?

Comment: @alexolut, перечитал принял. Я почему-то думал, что он 2015 предлагает как основной вариант.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Что касается формальностей, то официальное название — ***ECMA-262* *6th* Edition, The ECMAScript *2015* Language Specification**, то есть в названии спецификации присутствуют как служебные версии, так и "для людей". В целом, "ECMAScript 6" и "ECMAScript 2015" можно считать полноценными синонимами, как, скажем, "Visual Studio 14.0" и "Visual Studio 2015".

---

"ES" — это сокращение, а с ними много проблем: во-первых, очень часто возникают конфликты, во-вторых, их многие не знают, в-третьих, их может быть сложно искать в интернете. Почти всегда следует использовать полное написание.

Предлагаю основной меткой сделать [ecmascript-6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), а [es6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6) и [ecmascript-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015) сделать синонимами.

Собственно, на большом СО за основную метку принята [ecmascript-6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), [es6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6) является синонимом, а [ecmascript-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015) — предложенным синонимом (+1). Можете, кстати, [проголосовать](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ecmascript-6/synonyms), если у вас есть достаточно репутации по теме.

Впрочем, можно за основную принять и [ecmascript-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015), а не ориентироваться на традиции до появления названия. Учитывая, что это основное название, то "ES6" станет архаизмом, как, например, "C++0x".

Comment: Да, "ecmascript" в метке должно присутствовать. Иначе совсем непонятно, о чем речь.

Comment: С тех пор за синонимизацию проголосовали ещё двое )

Answer (score 2):

Считаю, что основной меткой должна быть [es6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6) по следующим причинам:

- На enSO метка [ecmascript-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015) практически не используется
- На ruSO по метке [es6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6) больше вопросов
- Эта метка короче альтернативной

Comment: Краткость метки — очень сомнительный аргумент.

Comment: @Discord, ну почему же. Я вот сомневаюсь, что новички в состоянии запомнить сочетание букв `ecmascript` ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev запоминать и не нужно, при синонимизации ввод короткой метки порождает длинную. Пишешь `es6`, получаешь `ecmascript-6` автоматически, например.

Answer (score 2):

А воз и ныне там.

С [ecmascript-6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) уже 145 вопросов, а с [ecmascript-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015) всего 14. Хоть Ecmascript 2015 и официальное название спецификации, но в текущих реалиях ru SO лучше [ecmascript-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015) синонимизировать к [ecmascript-6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6).

Comment: Чем лучше? Я, например, не вижу метки типа `ecmascript-5`, чтобы утверждать, что нужно выбрать `6` для единообразия.

Comment: @alexolut я по количеству вопросов сужу.

Comment: Это совершенно неважно при синонимизации. По сути идет борьба более короткой метки с официальным названием.

Comment: @alexolut. на enSO выбрали `6`, а дальше по годам.

Comment: К слову, в том же WebStorm при выборе версии JS показывает именно ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @Qwertiy на enSO много чего [не так, как у нас](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303985/339911).

Comment: Готово. // сс @alexolut

Comment: @Qwertiy теперь бы еще с [«шаблонами»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6439/176217) разобраться.

Comment: @alexolut, шаблоны ещё и разгребать надо...

Comment: @Qwertiy потихоньку, полегоньку )

Comment: @Qwertiy а кто у нас избирался делать сайт лучше? :-D